# Spring AOP: differences between && and 'and'

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

I have this interface:

```
public interface Performance {
    public void perform();
}
```

Implemented by this class:

```
@Component
public class PerformanceImplementation implements Performance {
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("PerformanceImplementation.perform()");
    }
}
```

I want to apply the following aspect to the method of the interface above but only if the method is executed within another package, so I use the `within` designator using that package name

```
@Aspect
public class Audience {

    @Pointcut("execution(** concert.Performance.perform(..)) " +
                "and within(asdasdasd.*)")
    public void performance() {}


    @Around("performance()")
    public void watchPerformance(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Silencing cell phones");
            System.out.println("Taking seats");
            jp.proceed();
            System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP!!!");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Demanding a refund");
        } }
}
```

If I use `and` instead of `&&` the aspect will be triggered anyway and it seems that it is not considering the limitation of the designator.

Is there any reason why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you are using them inside annotation or xml .

Pointcut expressions can be combined using '&&', '||' and '!'

```
@Pointcut("anyPublicOperation() && inTrading()")
private void tradingOperation() {}
```

When combining pointcut sub-expressions, '&&' is awkward within an XML document, and so the keywords 'and', 'or' and 'not' can be used in place of '&&', '||' and '!' respectively. For example, the previous pointcut may be better written as:

```
<aop:pointcut id="businessService"
        expression="execution(* com.xyz.myapp.service.*.*(..)) **and** this(service)"/>
```

Comment: I got this, but I cannot understand why it works with "&&" but not with "and".

Comment: which version of spring it is and is it working with capital letters ('AND' not 'and ') ? Some old versions of spring was having issues with lower case. Not sure though . But you have a valid question unless you are using old version.

Comment: It does not work in annotations with `and` because it is invalid syntax there. Just use the documented syntax for each case and be happy with it. Don't make a simple thing complicated, like asking: "Why can I not pay with Euro in the USA?"